# Finding minimum average value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a dictionary with 3 keys and for each key its value is a list of three numbers. I wanted to know how to use the built in min function to find the key with the lowest average number.
my list looks like this:

```
{'Tyler': [12.0, 50.0, 450.0],
 'Wesley': [100.0, 120.0, 900.0, 95.0],
 'Tim': [8.0, 150.0, 150.0]}
```

Comment: 'Wesley' has a value with 4 items, if all lists had equal length, you could use the sum instead of the mean

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `sum` and `len`:

```
min(d, key=lambda x: sum(d[x])/len(d[x]))
```

Output:

```
Tim
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from statistics import mean
dic = {'Tyler': [12.0, 50.0, 450.0],
       'Wesley': [100.0, 120.0, 900.0, 95.0],
       'Tim': [8.0, 150.0, 150.0]}
min(dic.items(), key=lambda x: mean(x[1]))[0]
```

Output: `'Tim'`

Or manually computing the mean:

```
min(dic.items(), key=lambda x: sum(x[1])/len(x[1]))[0]
```